# React-native google maps does not work?

Tags: google-maps, react-native

I am installing GoogleMaps on react-native cli. I got this error why?

** BUILD FAILED **

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Volumes/DATA/React\ Native/Redux-React-Native/reduxreactnative/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTDevSettings.o /Volumes/DATA/React\ Native/Redux-React-Native/reduxreactnative/node_modules/react-native/React/Modules/RCTDevSettings.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/reduxreactnative.app
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.reduxreactnative
org.reactjs.native.example.reduxreactnative: 23409
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by doing this

Troubleshooting
If you have a blank map issue, (#118, #176, #684), try the following lines :

On iOS:
If you have ran 'react-native link` by mistake:

```
delete node_modules
delete ios/Pods
delete ios/Podfile.lock
open Xcode and delete AIRMaps.xcodeproj from Libraries if it exists
in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries delete libAIRMaps.a if it exists
delete ios/build folder
start again with the installation steps
If you use Xcode with version less than 9 you may get use of undeclared identifier 'MKMapTypeMutedStandard' or Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist errors. In this case you have to update your Xcode.
```